# Convert Seq to Map by custom key

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

How do I convert the following JavaScript array to an Immutable.Map that is keyed by  the 'id' of each object in the list?

```
    id: 'all',
    label: 'All',
    isSelected: false
  }, {
    id: '1',
    label: '1',
    isSelected: true
  }, {
    id: '2',
    label: '2',
    isSelected: false
  }, {
    id: '3',
    label: '3',
    isSelected: false
}]
```

I'd like to be able to do:

```
// {id: 'all', label: 'All', isSelected: true}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `map.get('all')` returns `{id: 'all', label: 'All', isSelected: false}` ?

Comment: Yes. I've edited the question to correct the mistake. Thanks.

Comment: I've made this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ybL8n1r7/ that might be what you are looking for. If you still want the object notation (i. e., `map.get()` function) you should convert it to an object

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering how to achieve this with Immutable.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved completing using immutable JS like below.

```
var buttons = [{
    id: 'all',
    label: 'All',
    isSelected: false
  }, {
    id: '1',
    label: '1',
    isSelected: true
  }, {
    id: '2',
    label: '2',
    isSelected: false
  }, {
    id: '3',
    label: '3',
    isSelected: false
}];

buttonImmutableList = Immutable.fromJS(buttons)
buttonImmutableMap = buttonImmutableList.reduce((a,c)=>  a.set(c.get('id'),c), Immutable.Map())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using immutable:

```
var buttons = [{
    id: 'all',
    label: 'All',
    isSelected: false
  }, {
    id: '1',
    label: '1',
    isSelected: true
  }, {
    id: '2',
    label: '2',
    isSelected: false
  }, {
    id: '3',
    label: '3',
    isSelected: false
}];

var array = {};

for(var index in buttons) {
    var token = buttons[index];
    array[token.id] = token;
}

var map = new Immutable.Map(array);

var test = map.get('all');

window.alert(test.label);
```

In case you want to add key -> values later, the map is modified, and thus, the current instance invalidated. To do it, you need to reasign the variable `map` to the lastest returned valid instance:

`map = map.set(key, value);`

Comment: I was hoping to use Immutable to do the keying in a more functional manner rather than using a standard JavaScript for loop and array mutation. I am looking for an answer that uses Immutable.js to do all the work.

Comment: It is still not pure immutable.js, but without a for-loop and in a more functional manner might be the following: `const map = new Immutable.Map(buttons.map(button => [button.id, button]));`. Then you have a map and can access the values like you wish.

If you want to, you could also do the mapping with a Immutable.Seq, but this seems to be only overhead.

I created a small JSBin to play around: http://jsbin.com/wumilesogi/edit?js,output